# Pickleable partial class

Tags: python

I need to partially instantiate a class and later use in multiprocessing.
Multiprocessing pickles classes to pass between processes.
How can I pickle a partially instantiated class?

I'm targeting Python 3.8+

P.S. Here is my `partialclass` implementation:

```py
def partialclass(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    new_cls = type(cls.__name__, (cls,), {})
    new_cls.__init__ = partialmethod(cls.__init__, *args, **kwargs)

    return new_cls
```

EDIT: I thought about overriding `__reduce__` method, but class can potentially take arguments, which I don't know at the time of definition.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'partial instance'. You have a class, not an instance.

Comment: Why not just send across a real instance, one that is callable?

Comment: Because I need to send across a class, call functionality is already taken up by something else.

Comment: No, you are trying to send across a callable object. Classes are just callables in that regard. Just replace it with some other object that is callable like the class would be.

Comment: Would a simple class method that passes the desired arguments to `__new__`/`__init__` be sufficient?

Comment: Note: I've updated my answer further, as there actually is no point in re-creating `functools.partial` here, unless you really needed to distinguish between these objects and `functools.partial()` objects for some reason. But then I'd just subclass `functools.partial()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a *class*, not a 'partial instance'. Pickle doesn't serialise classes, as it assumes that all *code* can be loaded from source instead.

Instead, produce *instances* of a utility class, one that can be pickled, and when called does the same thing as calling your generated class:

```
class Partial:
    def __init__(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cls, self.args, self.kwargs = cls, args, kwargs

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.cls(*self.args, *args, **self.kwargs, **kwargs)
```

The class attributes are then pickled (here, a reference to a class object, a tuple and a dictionary), and you can call the instance to produce the actual class:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         self.a, self.k = args, kwargs
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f"<Foo(*{self.a!r}, **{self.k!r})>"
...
>>> pickled = pickle.dumps(Partial(Foo, "bar", monty="python"))
>>> partial = pickle.loads(pickled)
>>> partial("baz", spam="ham")
<Foo(*('bar', 'baz'), **{'monty': 'python', 'spam': 'ham'})>
```

However, the above is **basically** re-inventing the [`functools.partial()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which are instances of a utility class that can be pickled, and called, just like the above Python re-implementation:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> from functools import partial
>>> pickled = pickle.dumps(partial(Foo, "bar", monty="python"))
>>> fpartial = pickle.loads(pickled)
>>> fpartial("baz", spam="ham")
<Foo(*('bar', 'baz'), **{'monty': 'python', 'spam': 'ham'})>
```

`functools.partial()` is more memory efficient and faster, however.

The only possible  advantage would be that you could use `isinstance(object, Partial)` to distinguish it from `functools.partial()`. But you could just use subclassing for that too:

```
import functools

class CPartial(functools.partial): pass
```

and it'd work just the same.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will use functools.partial. I was under the impression that it only worked for functions, but I guess it works for classes as well.

Comment: @Rizhiy the documentation for partial() certainly doesn’t help there by talking about functions only, but in effect a class is a special function with some more attributes.. All *callable* objects work.